# Combining Salary with percentage of salary

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question in my mind...

suppose there are three employees in a dept having different salaries

> **e.g:** empA=1000, empB=1500 and empC=1200...

I require two columns one salaries of each employee and percentage of salaries out of total salary

```
empA 1000 27.03%
empB 1500 40.54%
empC 1200 32.43%
```

What can be the query?

Comment: Have you tried anything already?

Comment: no, I tried simple qurries.. like select ename, sum(salary).. but its not aloowing me to do so

Comment: why did they vote down my question??

Comment: Because you pretty much admitted you have done no work on this yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
    Emp,
    salary,
    CONVERT(numeric(18,2), CONVERT(numeric(18,2), salary)/(
        SUM(salary) over())*100) [Percent]
From tbl
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2680d/1)

Comment: Its little complicated for me as beginner.. I'll try, thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (empid int, empnave varchar(50), salary int)

insert into @t values 
(1,'empA', 1000),
(2,'empB', 1500),
(3,'empC', 1200)

select * from @t 

;with cte
as 
(
select SUM(salary) TotalSalary from @t 
)
select * , cast( salary*100/totalsalary as numeric(18,2)) PercentSalary   from @t , cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT E.Salary, (E.Salary*100)/X.SumSalaries 
   FROM Employee E, (SELECT SUM(Salary) AS SumSalaries FROM Employee) X
```